# How to set printexpr on MacVim persistently?

Tags: vimrc, macvim, printing

Using MacVim 8.1.1722, if I print a buffer, it opens a PDF in Preview.app. I want to open the PDF in Google Chrome instead. So I changed the file association so `open foo.pdf` opens Google Chrome not Preview.app. And then I set my `printexpr` in MacVIM as follows:

```
se printexpr=system('ps2pdf\ '.v:fname_in.'\ '.v:fname_in.'.pdf\ &&\ open\ '.v:fname_in.'.pdf')\ +\ v:shell_error
```

And using the above `printexpr`, it does what I want.

The problem is when I try to persist the above setting in `$HOME/.vimrc`. It doesn't take effect, upon restarting MacVim, `printexpr` still has the default value of

```
se printexpr=system('open\ '-a\ Preview\ '.v:fname_in)\ +\ v:shell_error
```

But if I set other related options, such as `se popt`, in `$HOME/.vimrc`, it does take effect. Also, the command line `vim` (VIM 7.4 shipped by Apple as part of macOS 10.12.6) does pick up the printexpr from that file.

So, how do I get my `printexpr` setting to persist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out myself. I need to add the setting to `$HOME/.gvimrc` as well.

If the setting is in `$HOME/.vimrc`, then MacVim overrides it. If the setting is in `$HOME/.gvimrc`, then MacVim doesn't override it.

Comment: Simon, great you figured it out. Although this is surprising. To find out were the setting is overridden, remove it from `.gvimrc` and restart Vim. Then execute `verbose set printexpr`. This will display were printexpr was last set.

Comment: It says: `Last set from /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/gvimrc line 37`. Looking in that file, I see a `set printexpr=` on that line, along with a comment above it explaining that it is to "Send print jobs to Preview.app"

Comment: @Ralf somethings are reset post-vimrc by the gui modes.